# WAMP Crossbar.io client and server

Tags: java, extjs, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I have just been introduced to the WebSocket Application Messaging Protocol WAMP http://wamp.ws/ and on googling I found the Crossbar.io implementation of the protocol.

I installed it by following http://crossbar.io/docs/Quick-Start/ and http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-Java/ .

My goal is to wire a Java server publishing real time messages to be displayed on a web browser. Could you point me in the right direction? Once I have that setup, I can proceed with structuring the data using Ext JS or similar JavaScript frameworks.

Comment: Please read this for how to ask an [On Topic Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is not a forum for seeking guidance to getting introduced to new technologies and alternatives.

Comment: Your question if fine, since it is about a "specific programming problem": how to publish real-time events from Java via WAMP.

Answer (score 1):

The [Getting Started with Java](http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-Java/) has all you need. Write your server-side program using the former. This component will then connect to Crossbar.io which does all the hard work of dispatching events in real-time to clients.